# How to bind a LinearLayout in Simple Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm developing an application that take data from the database and show their through a Listview. So I used a Simple Cursor Adapter with a Loader. 
Now i need to insert TextViews under the main title. So I tought to insert its in a Linear Layout and in this create programatically the TextViews beacause the number of their depends of the datas in Database.

```
--- Title of the row --- 
-- txt1 -- txt2 -- txt3 -- tx.... --
```

Without know how to bind a Linear Layout I created this row layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/doc_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/doc_note"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/doc_signed_date"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_starred"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:lines="1"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.BookDocListTitle" />
<!--
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/opaque_black" 
-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:id="@+id/doc_fields"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_tag"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/demo_txt"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So in the simple cursor adapter I bind the fake textview and from getParent a get access to Linear Layout to do my stuffs.. this is the code of the case in the bind:

```
case R.id.demo_txt:
                    if(cursor.getInt(LIST_COLUMN_INDEX_CODE) > 0)
                        listOfFields = sb.queryDocumentClasses(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(LIST_COLUMN_INDEX_CODE)));
                    ll = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    if(listOfFields != null){
                        for(DocumentField d: listOfFields){
                            if(d.isHighlighted()){
                                TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                txt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shp_round_corners));
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                params.setMargins(3, 0, 0, 0);
                                txt.setLayoutParams(params);
                                txt.setTag("field");
                                txt.setText("text");
                                ll.addView(txt);
                            }
                        }
                        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return false;
```

It's work great, but I have problems when i scroll the list because the adapter recycle views and the TextViews appears on rows that before they hadn't nothing.

Thanks..

Comment: is it a ViewBinder.setViewValue code?

Comment: Yes.. it is in the SetViewBinder

Comment: My main problem is to bind TextViews in SimpleCursorAdapter, without know the exact number for each row..

Comment: so for each row you have multiple (not fixed) number of TextViews?  if so what's the exact pribkem if you first delete them all before binding the new ones?

Comment: I resolved! the Trick is to return always True!